# How can I switch templates for the "attachment" page my images are displayed on?

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

Problem is, my images are showing up in search engines and the attachment page they're showing up on looks horrible. I messed it up when I used CSS to build the page templates that my regular content displays on.

Since my other pages look fine, I really don't want to rebuild whatever template the image attachment page uses. I'd rather just switch the template they display on if I can.

If I could, I would even just get rid of all the image attachment pages since they're just a damn nuisance.  I really don't want them appearing in search engine results at all.

I have no clue what php page template the images are using for the attachments page.  How can I find that out and change it? Is it single.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment pages range from using simply attachment.php file to almost a dozen other template files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display

**Attachment display**

Template file used to render a single attachment (attachment post-type) page.

1. MIME_type.php - it can be any MIME type (image.php, video.php,
   application.php). For text/plain, in order:

   1. text.php
   2. plain.php
   3. text_plain.php
2. attachment.php
3. single-attachment.php
4. single.php
5. index.php

You can have mime type specific templates for attachments. For example, over at my blog I have a snapshot of [JavaScript Meetup](http://www.giancarlocolfer.com/blog/new-haven-javascript-meetup-lightning-talks/5/new-haven-js-meetup-lightning-talks/) using the mime type specific image.php attachment template that handles image attachments.

So if your dealing with images, then I suggest you create an image.php file and drop that into your themes folder and get to work.